# Checking each element equivalence to 1

Tags: r, for-loop

```
division <- Residuals/Alignment
na.omit(division)
# savethis <- data.frame()

for(i in division) {
  if(c(i) == 1) {
    print("yes")
  }
}
```

Residuals and Alignments are both data frames. I am trying check the compare each element in division and print out yes for what is equal to 1. However I keep getting this error: the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used.

```
division <- structure(list(paf...10. = c(0.995815103671295, 0.995244435990108, 
0.999189408268036, 0.746572212065813, 0.744104599579734, 0.559049923026171
)), .Names = "paf...10.", row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: can you post `dput(head(division))` ?

Comment: structure(list(paf...10. = c(0.995815103671295, 0.995244435990108, 
0.999189408268036, 0.746572212065813, 0.744104599579734, 0.559049923026171
)), .Names = "paf...10.", row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not provide your data, but I can illustrate the problem with built in data.  I assume that Residuals and Alignments have similar structures so the division makes sense. What does division look like?

```
division <- iris[,1:4] / iris[,1:4]
str(division)
'data.frame':   150 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ Sepal.Length: num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Sepal.Width : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Petal.Length: num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Petal.Width : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

It is another data frame. What happens if you try to loop over a data.frame?

```
for(i in iris[,1:4]/iris[,1:4]) { print(str(i)) }
 num [1:150] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
NULL
 num [1:150] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
NULL
 num [1:150] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
NULL
 num [1:150] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
NULL
```

`i` successive takes on each of the *columns*. So your comparison `if(c(i) == 1)` is comparing an entire column to 1. `c(i) == 1` with be a vector of truth values. `if` does not work on a vector of comparisons, only on a scalar, so it gives this warning to let you know that it will only use the first element of your vector of comparisons.

If you want to compare every element with 1, you could use:

```
for(i in as.vector(as.matrix(division))) { 
  if(c(i) == 1) {
    print("yes")
  } 
}
```

Comment: division is one column of decimals that is taken from the division two columns of the same length

Comment: I want to compare each element to and print yes everytime I have a variable that is 1.00, but like you said it is comparing the whole column to 1

Answer (score 0):

It's because the data.frame you were referencing needed you to specify the target column:

```
division <- Residuals/Alignment
na.omit(division)
# savethis <- data.frame()

for(i in division$paf...10.) {
  if(c(i) == 1) {
    print("yes")
  }
}
```

Comment: I had specified the columns previously for the data frames, isn't that all I need: 
    ResidualsMatched_frame <- data.frame(paf[,10])
    AlignmentBlockLength <- data.frame(paf[,11])

Comment: @nathan no, you can't say "for i in ___dataframe___" it's "for i in "column_of_the_dataframe".  The division object you gave us is of class `data.frame`

Comment: Do you mean I would write the for loop as for(i in column_of_the_dataframe)?

Comment: Right, except I just typed `column_of_the_dataframe` as a placeholder for that column. Like in my answer it's `for(i in division$paf...10.)` . The column name there is messy because it looks like it was generated automatically. You could also use the column number like `for(i in division[,1])`